# Vpn problems with Ubuntu 12.04 are driving me mad. What further issue(s) could be contributing? And how do I fix it?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and have had to manually configure my vpn since the network manager just wont connect for unknown reasons. Additionally I cannot use openvpn or vpnc as I don't have assess to a CA certificate or group password respectively.

I appear to have it working, but cannot access (via ssh) the computers on the network. Ifconfig shows ppp0, however I cannot access the universities subscriptions to journals so I'm clearly not on the network.  With regards to manual configuration, what should the terminal display? I've used:

$sudo pon name nodetach debug

And the terminal show several sent and rcvd LCP EchoRep's.

I've checked with my internet provider to ensure that forward porting and firewalls are not an issue and I've tried to vpn from several different locations, nothing has worked. What further issues could be stopping me from accessing network machines? Has anyone else had this much trouble vpn-ing? What more can I do? Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: How do your routes look like? `ip r` or `route` will help you determine if your access is through the VPN or not.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Ok, so I'm new to route display and had to look it up: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node75.html . I've used the route command while the vpn command is running in another terminal. The vpn has the flag UH and so confirms that the vpn is up and only a single host can has been reached.  No gate way is used. Furthermore the interface is ppp0. Additionally two other variations of the vpn name exist with the flags UGH and interface wlan1. All appears good so far, any idea what else could be causing an issue with regards to ssh and network access?

Comment: Do you have a default route, a line in the route or ip r output that starts with "default"? What does `ip r get <ssh host ip>` tell you?